# Why do terminals sometimes echo special characters like ^C?

Tags: terminal, keyboard

When I run a GUI program from a terminal and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
I get echo from the terminal:

```
^C
```

Despite signal being delivered to the application (and presumably the key handled by the terminal). Why is the character echoed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character is echoed back because you have the `ECHO` flag on in the terminal settings, and is echoed *in the ^C form* because you *also* have the `ECHOCTL` flag on. Both flags are on by default on most systems. You can turn them on and off by using their lowercase form with the `stty(1)` utility:

```
stty -echoctl # turn echoctl off
stty echoctl  # turn echoctl on
```

You can refer to the `termios(3)` manpage on Linux for a description [1]:

> `ECHOCTL` (not in POSIX)
>
> **If `ECHO` is also set**, terminal special characters other than `TAB`, `NL`, `START`, and `STOP` are echoed as `^X`, where `X` is
>   the character with ASCII code  `0x40`  greater  than  the  special
>   character.   For  example,  character `0x08` (`BS`) is echoed as `^H`. [requires `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_SVID_SOURCE`]

Notice that turning *just* the `ECHOCTL` flag off will **not** prevent control characters from being echoed back, but will cause them to be echoed back in their raw form, rather than in the `^X` caret form. The fact that a character is special and will generate a signal (eg. `^C` -> `VINTR` -> `SIGINT`) does not affect in any way whether it will be echoed back or not.

Most terminal emulators will not display the control characters in any way (unfortunately), but they may interpret them in funny ways: for an illustrative example, start a command like
`sleep 3600` or `cat > /dev/null`, then on the next line press the `<Escape>[41m foo<Enter>` keys. With `echoctl` on, you'll have `^[[41m foo` printed on your screen, and nothing special will happen. But with `echoctl` off, the terminal will interpret the echoed back `<Raw_esc>[41m` as an ANSI color escape (without displaying any of the `[41m`, etc) and will turn the background red.

Depending on the terminal emulator and its settings, an emacs user pressing `^N` by reflex may end up switching to the alternate character set, and turn all the letters into line-drawing squiggles.

You usually don't want these to happen, thence `ECHOCTL` can be  considered a reasonable default.

---

[1] That description is not very accurate:

- It's not the "terminal special characters" which are echoed in that caret form, but the *control characters* (ASCII `0x0 - 0x1f` and `0x7f`), no matter if they're special or not. If you define `Q` as the `VINTR` "terminal special character" (replacing the default `^C`, eg. with `stty intr Q`), it will still be echoed back as simply `Q`, not as `^Q` or `chr(0x91)`.
- On Linux, `VEOF` will not be echoed back (as `^D` or in any other form) when the `ICANON` flag is also set. But it *will* be echoed back in that case too on *BSD and MacOS.
- ASCII `0x7f` (`DEL`) will not be displayed as `char + 0x40` (as described), but as `char ^ 0x40` (`^?`). Just like all the others, btw ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Run this, it's just a terminal setting, by default, everything you type is echoed :

```
stty -ctlecho
```

Now, your terminal is set to not display these characters.

```
man stty | less +/ctlecho
```

> [-]ctlecho
>   echo control characters in hat notation ('^c')

To keep this configuration permanently, add it to your *rc file. (`~/.bashrc` or such).

To list `stty` settings, just type the command alone.

Comment: The question was not _How do I turn off the echo?_ though.  It was _Why is the character echoed?_, which this answer does not in fact give an answer to, leaving the questioner to _infer_ an unstated answer, without even the word "canonical" as a clue.

Comment: By default, everything you type is echoed, on the basis you might find it interesting . Sending a SIGINT to the foreground process is probably more interesting than most things, I guess. Particularly if one of your users thought they were doing a cut/paste of their output from a script you supplied, and then complains to your manager that it broke because you wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The Unix-style terminal connections were originally developed for much slower (9600 bps or even less) connections, potentially over dial-up modem lines which might introduce transmission errors. The echo feature is produced by the TTY driver, before any application gets the input, although applications may disable the echo feature if necessary.

When connecting to a heavily-loaded server and/or over a slow connection, the echoing of all characters will give you feedback that the characters were received without errors. So, when you see a `^C`, you'll know that your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keystroke was correctly received by the remote computer. If there is no immediate further response, you'll now know that the problem is not with the communication.

For example, it might be that the system is too busy to immediately present a new command prompt; or it might be that the interrupted program or script has a SIGINT handler that either executes some actions (e.g. backing up any unsaved data) before exiting, or outright ignores the interrupt signal.